# Redirecting function output to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to redirect of print statement of `reporterror` function into file but output of print statement did not redirect into text file
May I know what am i missing here
**Please note I have created one live scenario here and I can not modify report
error function as it's in framework and modificaition will require lot of testing**

```
import os

def reporterror():
    print ("file not found")
    errors = ["error", "error1", "error3"]
    for er in errors:
        print (er)
    return 1
    
def info():
    print (os.getcwd())
    with open("info.txt", "w") as finfo:
        print(reporterror(), file=finfo)
   
info()
```

Output in .txt file:

> 1

Expected output:

> error
> error1
> error2

Comment: `reporterror()`  doesn't return anything, so it doesn't make sense to print its output. If you want to redirect STDOUT to a file, you can do that through the command line.

Comment: f you can't change `reporterror`, you will have to change `sys.stdout` as this is the default for `print`. In that case...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: I just create a scenario here and need to invoke function here

Comment: it is redirect out of file But I need to invoke function Thx I have already gone through link

Comment: your comments are more confusing than your question. What do you want to happen to the print statements in reporterrror? Maybe you need to monkey-patch or decorate reporterror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has already shared the link to the top answer on redirecting stdout but you haven't picked up on the part in that answer that might help.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        my_function() #Call your function here any prints will go to the file
        print("This text") #This will be output to the file too
```

This will temporarily redirect the output of print to the log.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You expect the print statements that are inside `reporterror()` to also write to the file. However, this is not the case. The only thing that happens here is that `reporterror()` returns `1` and prints each value in `errors`. The print statements in `reporterror()` do not just *inherit* the file from the print statement in `info()`. Below, I return a string that contains all of the values in `errors` followed by a line break. The print statement inside of `info()` will now print the output of `reporterror()`.

```
import os

def reporterror():
    errors = ["error", "error1", "error3"] 
    return "\n".join(errors)

def info():
    print (os.getcwd())
    with open("info.txt", "w") as finfo:
        print(reporterror(), file=finfo)

info()
```

If you want to capture all output, regardless of whether or not the print statements specify an output file, you can redirect the scripts output into a .txt file through the terminal:

```
python script.py > info.txt
```

It should be worth noting that unless you have a valid reason for using `print()` to write to a file, it is really better off to just use:

```
file.write(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the print statements (AKA standard output `stdout`) output to be redirect to a specific file
just use this snippet

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('<<<PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE>>>', 'w')
print('test')
```

this shall do it.